# WatiN SelectList element select by index

Tags: c#, watin, selectlist

Ho do I select the first item in a SelectList in WatiN?  Below you can see how I have my selectlist declared and below that is how I'm attempting to call the select.  I don't see any options for index.  Will I need to get a string collection of selected items and select by the [1] string or is there a simpler way to do this?

Page Class:

```
[FindBy(Id = "VariationRelationshipId")]
public SelectList VariationRelationship { get; set; }
```

Test Class:

```
//need to select 1st item in list
Browser.Page<MyPage>().VariationRelationship........
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be calling against an instance of a browser, not the `Watin.Core.Browser` class

Test code.

```
IE myBrowser = new IE(true);
myBrowser.GoTo("http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlselect.php");           
myBrowser.Page<DropDownSample>().States.WaitUntilExists();
myBrowser.Page<DropDownSample>().States.Options[2].Select();  //<-- not Browser.Page....
```

Class

```
public class DropDownSample : Page
    {
        [FindBy(Name = "selectionField")]
        public SelectList States { get; set; }
    }
```

Above checked on Watin2.1, IE9, Win7 - runs like a champ.  Selects "conneticut" in the first select list on the page.

Comment: What is the benefit to calling an instance over the default browser?

Comment: Browser (capital B) is a class, not a default browser.  *Note:  If you have yourself declared a variable named Browser (capital B), you are going to run into "fun" conflicts between that variable and the WatiN.Core.Browser class.

Comment: I haven't looked into the code too much but it looks like our BaseTest class returns a static instance of browser which defaults to IE unless otherwise specified in a separate setup file.  In any case, Browser seems to work and being Scrum, the porting cost is too high to switch convention without a story to do so (this test suite is HUGE and all our init scripts use Browser).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on selecting by index by the way.  I'm ran into another issue but if this works, I'll mark as solution.